# Is it safe if memory is not allocated from heap for string literal?

Tags: c++

```
class MyString
{
    char* str;
public:
    MyString(char* _str)
    {
        str = _str;
    }
};

int main()
{
   MyString obj1("hi");   // case 1
   char str[] = "hi";
   MyString obj2(str);  // case 2 
}
```

Here I have not allocated memory from heap in constructor for member str. Is it safe both case 1 and case 2? if not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First case is OK because "hi" is a static string - a global constant. It will live at least as long as obj1 (even if obj1 were a global or were allocated on the heap).

The second case is potentially not OK because "hi is copied into str[] on the stack.

In this particular case, obj2 is destroyed before str, so it is fine. If you were to return a copy of obj2 or it was itself allocated on the heap, then it would be a problem because it could outlive str.

The data of str ([ 'h', 'i', '\0']) is on the stack - the same as a local variable.
This memory is only valid as long as it stays in scope - in this case, until main() returns.
Since obj2 is also on the stack, it essentially has the same lifetime as str, so there is no problem in this instance.
More generally though, you might create an instance of this object with a different lifetime, perhaps like "MyString *s = new MyString(str); return s;". Now that MyString object will outlive str, and will continue point at the memory where str used to be causing undefined behavior. 
This is a common source of often difficult to find bugs.

Comment: Can you please explain your last paragraph. if possible give an example

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, it is not safe, but not because of where the memory is allocated, but because `"hi"` is of type `const char*` (might be on .text or .data who knows), and the contructor for `MyString` is assigning it to a variable of type `char*`. If something tried to modify the string through `str`, undefined behavior would happen.

The problem with the second case is that your object `obj2` points to a string to which it has no ownership, doesn't matter if it is stack or heap. It is not a terrible thing to do, I've seen legitimate uses for this, but it must be done with care. This particular example will work fine because both object and string live in the stack, and because it is very simple.

Comment: WRT "const char *": Depending on your compiler and environment, you  may get something like an access-violation if you were to attempt to modify it. Particularly in old compilers, this was not a problem - strings were not constant, nor pooled, so it was usually OK to modify them. (By OK I mean well defined, not that it was ever a particularly good idea).

Comment: Actually, the Standard specifies that string literals are of type "array of n `const char`". So even if you can get away with modifying one, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Sigh -- you are right. Even the C99 standard says it is undefined. However, in K&R C, they don't say (I guess you could take this to mean undefined). They do say that "string" is "char *" (because K&R C didn't have 'const'), and they say each is unique - explicitly not allowing string merging. In K&R C it was OK to modify such strings. I think this is why the MSFT C compiler still has an option to enable/disable string constant merging and I think also to control if strings are placed in read-only memory or read-write memory.